# iOS post to the Facebook app wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am wondering if it is possible to post to the wall of the Facebook app page created for using Facebook in iOS. Rather than use the user login to post to their own wall, I would like to post to the app's page with updates on open games. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/:

> To perform the following operations as an Application Page, and not the current user, you must use the Application's Page access token, not the user access token commonly used for modifying Graph API objects nor the Application access token. This access token can be retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including Application profile pages) to which the user has administrative access, along with an access_token for each Page.
>
> …
>
> You can create a link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the APP_ID/feed connection. To see more details please see links, posts, and status messages documentation.
>
> To impersonate the Application when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the Application, and not the current user), you must use an Application Page access_token with the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under Application Access Tokens above.

So you first have to ask the API for an Application Page access token and then use this access token to post on the wall. The Facebook iOS SDK helps to construct the Graph API calls mentioned in the documentation cited above.

Comment: "To impersonate the Application when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the Application, and not the current user), you must use an Application Page access_token with the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under Application Access Tokens above."    This is what I would like to do, but how do I get the App Page Access Token? It says in the documentation to do: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials       but what does that give me? Thanks!

Comment: No, the call you mention gives you an App Login Access Token, which is not the same. You need to retrieve an App Page Access Token, and you get this by logging in with a user that has permissions to administer the App Page, and then GETting `/USER_ID/accounts`, as described above.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. So I did that and sent the HTTP POST to the page, and I get the response http://graph.facebook.com/245547652122925_282887395055617. This shows that it posted to Facebook, but on the actual page, there is no post. Any idea why?

Comment: I am getting    {
            category = Application;
            id = 245547652122925;
            name = "Telephone Pictionary";
        }      in the response from the accounts request and then using the id/feed to post. Is there somewhere I am supposed to get the access token?

Comment: Got it figured out. Thanks for the help!