# iOS Facebook cannot post on another user's wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-wall

I am trying to make a post on another user's wall using another user using FBConnect. I am using the embedded method of the iOS Facebook API (that is, I am forcing the browser to appear inside my app, so I am not leaving the application at all). This method works for posting into the wall of the same user, but doesn't work on the wall of another user.

```
    self.facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:self.appID andDelegate:self] autorelease];
if ([self.facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [self proceedToPost];
}else{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"email", @"read_stream", @"manage_pages", nil];
    [self.facebook authorize:permissions];
}

- (void)proceedToPost
```

{

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"aName", @"name",
                               self.appID, @"app_id",
                               self.title, @"caption",
                               self.link, @"link",
                               @"animateURL", @"picture",
                               nil];
[params setObject:"my-user-profile-id" forKey:@"to"];
[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

}

The problem is that authorization is done as expected, but when trying to actually post, I see an error message in the embedded browser "cannot post to user's wall".

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you request the publish_stream permission from the extended permissions?

From the documentation about publish_stream permission:

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

You can request permissons like this:

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"publish_stream",
            nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
```

Comment: I did that, and it keeps showing me the same error messages. Note that when I try to call this using my browser using HTTP requests, I can successfully post to the page. I have also added the application using these permissions to my Facebook profile that handles the page.

Comment: Are you sure? in the code you posted I see  [self.facebook authorize:nil]; Meaning you don't include the permissions NSArray? Or did you change this allready?

Comment: I just changed this to no effect. You are right, I should edit my first post

Comment: NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"aName", @"name",
                               self.appID, @"app_id",
                               self.title, @"caption",
                               self.link, @"link",
                               @"animateURL", @"picture",           @"user-profile-id" , @"to",
                               nil]; Should be the same as yours i suppose.

Comment: Yes, they are. it seems that I can post to my wall, and another user's wall by setting the "to" parameter. However, when I change the "to" parameter to a Page, not a user, then it will give me errors :Error with publishing
An invalid target was specified: 125190674229524. The target must be a page, event, or user that the actor can post on the wall of. And sometimes it gives me an error code 1

Comment: very nice. now try this page... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495472/ios-post-to-the-facebook-app-wall