# Opening the native facebook app to a pre-filled post

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to open the facebook iOS app with a post pre-filled. Is this something I can do with the facebook url scheme, or do I need to use the facebook SDK?

I'm aware of this:
[iOS post to the Facebook app wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495472/ios-post-to-the-facebook-app-wall)

But I'm really interested in a lightweight solution.

Comment: Prefilling the message is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info.